# double windows authentication needed

Tags: windows, authentication, authorization, winlogon

we have a scenario where a couple of workstation needs to be started by a service account + login + starting some services (requirement of 3rd party software which is used, and need of avoiding time loss between user logoff/logon when shift is changing). 
But we need to know which person is in front of the computer, so we have an idea to start into a second logon screen for which the user has to input his credentials and where he is able to "logout". After logging out the special logon form has to appear again and lock all other interactions. 
Is there white paper for doing such things before starting with possibly the wrong approach.

thx & br for any hints.

Comment: I have very little experience with MS-Windows, but why should that be required? Services are usually started by operating systems independent of a user login. So everything should be ready when a user starts his session. And that login should only take a second or so.

Comment: we have time critical applications which should run without a break in 24/7 operations. It should not be necassary to logoff/on when shift is changing but we need to know who is using the computer

Comment: You mean you run business critical applications with a requirement of uninterrupted uptime on an MS-Windows based desktop system? Well... Anyway, maybe you should take a look into authentication dongles able to unlock the system. It should be possible to read those devices at runtime by the applications.

Comment: this is a nice hint! i will give it a try, thx